# QoS user-interactive and updating the UI

Tags: ios, multithreading, uikit, grand-central-dispatch

On iOS, the UI should only be updated via the main thread, but what intrigues me is that in the documentation, the User-interactive quality of service is defined like that :

> Work that is interacting with the user, such as operating on the main
>   thread, **refreshing the user interface, or performing animations**. If
>   the work doesn’t happen quickly, the user interface may appear frozen.
>   Focuses on responsiveness and performance.

The problem is that, if you call `dispatch_get_global_queue` with that QoS, the queue that is returned won't be the main queue, am I right ? Therefore, how could work submitted to that queue refresh the UI ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dispatch_get_global_queue will always give you the global concurrent queue. You cannot update the ui in that queue as in any queue besides the main.

As with User interactive Qos, it is used for work that is critical to the ui and the results are needed as fast as possible.

A good example is that you have an image that needs processing. You can process the image in global_queue with User-Interactive Qos and when it's done you set the result image in your imageView (this is done in main queue).

Comment: Thank you ! Now I understand better.